# solving equations involving 3rd degree

Tags: quadratics

I got the below question

x^3-10x^2+Px-30=0 find the value for P. How this can be answered?  If I give different values for x, it gives different values for P.  Is this question wrong?

Comment: There must be some other hypothesis...

Comment: If no further conditions on $P$ or $x$ are given, the equation is underdetermined (it cannot be solved).